# How to make the system menu a toggle button than a dropdown

Tags: swift

So I made this [simple Cocoa app](https://github.com/SaifurRahmanMohsin/ToggleDesktopIcons/tree/22087fc4c36b48cbce0b7e9439763aa682eb2ac1). I’m a beginner to Swift and was just experimenting with it. This app toggles between hide/show desktop icons by clicking the menu item from the status bar item’s dropdown. I don’t want such a dropdown to happen and rather just directly toggle between show/hide desktop states on clicking it. How can I achieve this using Swift?

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution that worked for me: Implement the NSMenu delegate method `menuNeedsUpdate(menu: NSMenu)` to detect the click, remove all menu items and do your click action within this method.

```
func menuNeedsUpdate(menu: NSMenu) {
    menu.removeAllItems()
    NSLog("menu clicked !")
}
```

Don't forget to set the menu's delegate in the same class so that your method will be called.

```
statusMenu.delegate = self
```